# Google Script logger not showing what sheet edit was made on from event data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to detect what sheet an edit was made on during an installed `onEdit` function.

The logger correctly records the data of the cell being edited however does not tell me what sheet this edit was made on. I need specifically to ID what sheet the edit took place on in order to complete a function I am building.

Logger:

```
[19-08-01 08:37:27:714 CDT] {"authMode":{},"range":{"columnStart":4,"rowStart":4,"rowEnd":4,"columnEnd":4},"source":{},"oldValue":"2.0","triggerUid":"1111111","user":{"nickname":"Mike-SMT","email":"Mike-SMT@random.com"},"value":"222"}
```

Code used to log event:

```
function raw_data_edited(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

I do not see anything in the above log that would indicate specific sheet.

Is there a way to ID sheet from event?

Comment: This may help? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: @ArnovanBoven I know all that stuff but in the above log `source` is empty... I need the sheet to be there 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, `source` always seems to show as empty when logging the event object, but can still be used.

I wasn't sure if you meant *spreadsheet* ID or *sheet* ID, so here's how to get both using event objects:

```
//get spreadsheet id using "source" object
e.source.getId();

//get spreadsheet id using "range" object
e.range.getSheet().getParent().getId();

//get individual sheet id using "source" object
e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();

//get individual sheet id using "range" object
e.range.getSheet().getSheetId();
```

---

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [`getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getId())
- [`getSheetId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId())

Comment: Thanks ross. `e.source.getActiveSheet()` was what I was needing. I can get specif cell data now from the sheet that was edited. Odd that the JSON stringify doesnt name the sheet object in the string. Must not be possible to convert object name to string I guess. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike-SMT great, you could also use `e.range.getSheet()` to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Hum. I wonder what one is faster to get the sheet then. Google sheets has a problem with concurrency so the faster the better.

Comment: From a very short testing period they seem to perform the same. Also might be worth looking into the `LockService` if you're having some concurrency issues.

Comment: I did start looking into `LockService` however I found a way around the concurrency issue I was having by grabbing event data `rowStart` and that appears to have got rid of all the issues I was having for the function I made.

Answer (score 1):

`e.range` will get you the range that was edited.

From there you can use `getSheet()` to [get the sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getSheet()) that this range belongs to.

And then from the sheet, use `getSheetId()` to [get the ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId()) of the sheet

```
function raw_data_edited(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ssID = e.range.getSheet().getSheetId().toString();
  Logger.log(ssID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful info but ross had what I needed with `e.source.getActiveSheet()`.